# Global variables in XQuery and not sure how to return the average and why I am getting this error

Tags: xml, xquery

I have been working on my 2nd simple query for a few days. All I am supposed to do is declare a global variable ($crimes) that points to all crime elements in the XML file and use a FLWOR query to iterate through each unique value of the day element so that I can see which days have the most crimes (it should be Saturday, Monday, and then Sunday in order). I also keep getting this error:

> Unexpected end of query; variable "$crimes".

Code:

```
    xquery version "1.0";
delare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')//crime;

(: 

   Query to display total number of crimes by
   day of the week
 :)
<results>{
    for $day in distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml')/$day
    let $crimes := sum($crimes/($day/$crimes))
    order by $day descending order

    return
    <crime day="{$day}" crimes="{$count}">{$crimes}</crime>
}</results>
```

Sample of XML:

```
       <crime id="13402531">
      <dateTime>2013-08-31T20:27:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>7-Sat</day>
      <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>3</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13402533">
      <dateTime>2013-08-28T17:06:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>4-Wed</day>
      <offense>THEFT F/AUTO</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>1</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13402547">
      <dateTime>2013-08-31T20:05:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>7-Sat</day>
      <offense>THEFT F/AUTO</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>6</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13402704">
      <dateTime>2013-08-03T17:29:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>7-Sat</day>
      <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>2</ward>
   </crime>
</crimes>
```

Please help...

Comment: There are too many syntax errors and undeclared variables in the XQuery posted, it isn't clear which part is a typo and which you actually misunderstand.. please check again and fix the typos

Comment: @har07: Sorry about that, very exhausted, but I did edit some obvious errors that I should have noticed and will continue to work on it regardless. The most confusing parts are the global variable and how exactly to calculate the average day(s) that the most crimes occur on.. Also still getting the same error. Thank you

Comment: You misspelt "declare" as "delare". No idea why that should result in this error message. But because XQuery doesn't have reserved words, a simple misspelling can send the parser down the wrong track, and once it's gone down the wrong track it can get very confused when it gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XQuery that: **1.** uses global variable and **2.** count number of crimes per day and return the result in the order of that number, descending :

```
declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')//crime;

<results>{
    for $day in distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml')//day)
    (: get all crimes that happen at current day of week :)
    let $details := $crimes[day=$day] 
    (: count number crimes that happen at current day of week :)
    let $count := count($details)
    (: return the result in the order of $count, descending :)
    order by $count descending

    return
    <crime day="{$day}" crimes="{$count}">{$details}</crime>
}</results>
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/b768626880e67fa32631d46f3b7b8c4a)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<results>
   <crime crimes="3" day="7-Sat">
      <crime id="13402531"> 
         <dateTime>2013-08-31T20:27:00</dateTime>  
         <month>8-Aug</month>  
         <day>7-Sat</day>  
         <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>  
         <method>OTHERS</method>  
         <ward>3</ward> 
      </crime>
      <crime id="13402547"> 
         <dateTime>2013-08-31T20:05:00</dateTime>  
         <month>8-Aug</month>  
         <day>7-Sat</day>  
         <offense>THEFT F/AUTO</offense>  
         <method>OTHERS</method>  
         <ward>6</ward> 
      </crime>
      <crime id="13402704"> 
         <dateTime>2013-08-03T17:29:00</dateTime>  
         <month>8-Aug</month>  
         <day>7-Sat</day>  
         <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>  
         <method>OTHERS</method>  
         <ward>2</ward> 
      </crime>
   </crime>
   <crime crimes="1" day="4-Wed">
      <crime id="13402533"> 
         <dateTime>2013-08-28T17:06:00</dateTime>  
         <month>8-Aug</month>  
         <day>4-Wed</day>  
         <offense>THEFT F/AUTO</offense>  
         <method>OTHERS</method>  
         <ward>1</ward> 
      </crime>
   </crime>
</results>
```